# Recent workspaces setting in Eclipse 4.3 Kepler

Tags: eclipse

Where is the recent workspaces setting in Eclipse Kepler?
In old Eclipse version was in a configuration file, but now that file there is not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Recent workspaces is in the `configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` file in the Eclipse installation directory.

This location did not change for Kepler.

Comment: Actually I haven't that directory!

Comment: All Eclipse installations have this directory. It is in the Eclipse installation **not** the workspace. On Linux and Macs the `.settings` directory will be hidden so you need to use something that can show hidden directories.

Answer (score 0):

I've found where is it: differently from old Eclipse version now it's in the Preferences menu setting, exactly in:
Window - Preferences - General - Startup and Shutdown - Workspaces.